# how to save POST/GET requests of a browser session?

Tags: post, browser, get, intercept

I am analyzing the `POST`/`GET` requests and responses of a web site the API I want to use. Since the traffic is `HTTPS` I use Firebug on Firefox (as opposed to a proxy like ZAP) - it works great.

I cannot, however, save a session for later analysis.

Which extension would you recommend (Chrome/FF) that would capture `POST`/`GET` requests and responses and allow the session to be saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). It allows to break (decode/encode) `HTTPS` traffic in an intuitive way. The session you save can be annotated, pruned from uninteresting lines, etc.